# what can i do to let python use complement code to interpret bits just like c do

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

In fact, I just want Python to do the same thing as c do.

for example, in c:

`int num = 1 << 31;        // num's bits should be 0x8000 0000.`

`printf("%d\n", num);      // the print is -2147483648, because of complememnt.`

however, in Python:

```
>>> num = 1 << 31
>>> print num
2147483648
>>> print int.bit_length(num)
32
>>> print '{0:b}'.format(num)
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

it seems that Python use true code to interpret the num. what can i do to let python use complement code to interpret bits just like c do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `ctypes` module you can get the result you are looking for:

```
    import ctypes
    ctypes.c_int(1 << 31)
```

I hope this is sufficient for what you would like to do next with this integer. Python is much more forgiving than C with integers: it even avoids overflow by upgrading to a larger representation (e.g. int to long) when necessary to hold the result of an operation. Nice to have for better abstraction, but does complicate things when going lower level.

Comment: To get a python integer, `ctypes.c_int(1 << 31).value`